# How to work with REST API using Ember data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use ember data with `REST API` from server. The project is quiet simple and works fine with `Fetch API`, but i would like to implement the same result using `Ember data` and understand it's principles. I could not use `ember twiddle` with this configuration. Below will be the main parts of the project. It was made by `Ember CLI` version 4.0.1.

The `JSON` responce from url `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items` looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "description": "12345",
    "created_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Item 2",
    "description": "22222",
    "created_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:29.787Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:29.787Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Item 3",
    "description": "33333",
    "created_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:37.885Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:37.885Z"
  }
]
```

The responce from a single item request such as `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/1`:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "description": "12345",
    "created_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z"
}
```

`app/models/item.js`:

```
import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class ItemModel extends Model {
  @attr name;
  @attr description;
}
```

`app/routes/items.js`:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class ItemsRoute extends Route {
  @service store;
  async model() {
    return this.store.findAll('item');
  }
}
```

`app/routes/item.js`:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class ItemRoute extends Route {
  @service store;
  async model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('item', params.id);
  }
}
```

`app/templates/items.hbs`:

```
{{#each @model as |item|}}
  <LinkTo @route='item' @model={{item}}>{{item.name}}</LinkTo>
{{/each}}
```

`app/adapters/application.js`:

```
import RESTAdapter from '@ember-data/adapter/rest';

export default class ItemAdapter extends RESTAdapter {
  host = 'http://localhost:3000';
  namespace = 'api/v1';

  buildURL(...args) {
    return `${super.buildURL(...args)}.json`;
  }
}
```

`app/serializers/application.js`:

```
import RESTSerializer from '@ember-data/serializer/rest';

export default class ItemSerializer extends RESTSerializer {}
```

`app/router.js`:

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from 'dist/config/environment';

export default class Router extends EmberRouter {
  location = config.locationType;
  rootURL = config.rootURL;
}

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('items');
  this.route('item', { path: '/:id' });
});
```

When I move to route `/items` on the ember client, the following error appears in the console:

> WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model
> name "0" (resolved model name using
> <dist@serializer:item::constructor>.modelNameFromPayloadKey("0"))

And the same errors for "1" and "2". The template doesn't render links in the `each` loop.

Probably, there are some features in `Ember data` with `REST API`, and I would really like to figure it out. Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have this issue because your data is not in the `RESTSerializer` format but rather in the `JSONSerializer` [one](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_jsonserializer):

> the JSONSerializer expects the response to be a JSON object that looks
> similar to this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Rails is omakase",
  "tag": "rails",
  "comments": ["1", "2"]
}
```

So i guess you should just use this one.

If for any reason you wanna keep the `RESTSerializer` you should return your data similar to this format:

```
{
"item":
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "description": "12345",
    "created_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z"
  }
}
```

or for a list

```
{
"items": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "description": "12345",
    "created_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-07T11:43:21.755Z"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you (Спасибо большое, все сработало)!